# EJB Schedule task with access to JSF Managed Beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb

I have a feeling I'm mixing EJB and JSF managed bean responsibilities, but what I want is a scheduled task EJB (`@Singleton` with `@Schedule`) that has access to my JSF application scoped beans.

Specifically, I have a JSF `@ApplicationScoped` bean that sends different e-mails depending on if it's in Development, Test, or Production.  I want to schedule this to send e-mails every 24 hours.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does the EJB need the `@ApplicationScoped` bean for? The EJB by itself should be able to generate and send the emails. Is there some information in the web tier that the EJB will need to perform it's function? Trying to establish a dependency from the EJB to the managed bean is a grave design flaw. The dependency should be from the web tier to the business(EJB) tier

Comment: The EJB needs to know the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` variable from web.xml to determine DEV, TEST, or PROD.  That's currently coming from an application bean. My main reason for involving an EJB is the simplicity of the `@Schedule` notation.

Comment: That's too trivial a requirement to bind the two layers together like that IMO. Externalize the config to a properties file that both components have access to.

Comment: That's a good idea, I think I'll externalize it to a JNDI lookup so I don't have to mess with multiple property files for different environments. Thanks!

Comment: @kolossus don't waste rep, post an answer

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, thanks, good looking out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bad design to set the business layer (EJB) as dependent on the Presentation layer. The reverse (Web tier depending on Business tier) is the time tested best practice.

The EJB tier is to provide services to the web tier. Your use case seeks to make the web tier provide services to the EJB tier. And the need, IMO is too trivial to make such a compromise.
I'd recommend instead that you externalize the desired config in a `.properties` file within a secure location in your application that both tiers have access to.